# How to initialize a property as false in constructor?

Tags: javascript

let's say you have a simple class:

```
class Example {
  constructor(options) {
  this.active = options.active || true;
  }

}
```

How can you initialize `this.active` as false at constructor?
I want to pass new Example({active: false}) with default to true.

Comment: You'd have to change  the constructor.

Comment: @Pointy hmmm... change the constructor.... you mean to make it default to false?

Comment: No, to make it default to `true`.  I'll post an answer.

Comment: If you think about your question differently, it sounds like you're simply saying *set `this.active` to `false` only if `options.active` is `false`, otherwise it should be set to `true`*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the way your constructor is coded, passing `false` in the options will still leave the flag initialized to `true`:

```
    this.active = options.active || true; // always true
```

I'd do something simple like this:

```
    this.active = ("active" in options) ? options.active : true;
```

That way, if the passed-in options contain *any* value for the flag, then use that; otherwise, if not specified, use `true`.

Comment: How about `this.active = options.active !== false`?

Comment: @KirkLarkin that would work too, though it makes the API a little fragile. It forces the client code to make sure it's passing an actual boolean and not just a "falsy" value computed somehow.

Answer (score 0):

This will make your attribute always set to true. Read more about logical [OR statement](https://www.google.tn/search?q=logical%20or%20statement&oq=logical%20or%20statement&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.3004j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

```
this.active = options.active || true // true no matter what
```

You can use the `not equal value or not equal type` operator `!==`

```
this.active = options.active !== false // true or false depending on options.active value and type
```

Read more about JavaScript [Comparison Operators.](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use deconsturing with default values for that. Like this

```
constructor({active = false}) {
  this.active = active
}
```

Just make sure you pass some object to constuctor.